# i want to navigate from a page to an other page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i want to navigate from a page(not main page) which is in a tabbed page to a page when clicking on a button. i tried this :

```
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new listofinterest());
        MainPage = new  TabbedPageMain()
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#F8F8F8"),

        };
```

////////

```
public partial class listofinterest : ContentPage
{
    private async void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MainPage()));
    }
}
```

it didn't work i get this error
"PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'"
i need help please.

Comment: `listofinterest` needs to be contained within a `NavigationPage` when you assign it to the tabbed page.  Something like `myTabbedPage.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new listofinterest()));`

Comment: i have tried this .It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your overriding the `MainPage` with the `TabbedPageMain`. Only set it once.

First set the MainPage in App.xaml.cs:

```cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
```

Then you can push other pages from `MyPage` like this:

```cs
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyOtherPage());
```

Comment: when i tried to overriding mainpage with the new page the tabbedpage is not shown

Comment: Check out this demo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-tabbedpagewithnavigationpage/

Answer (score 0):

> it didn't work i get this error "PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'" i need help please.

From your code and description, you want to navigate from one of Tabbedpages to other page in project. If yes, please add to a navigation stack is referred to as the root page of the application in App.xaml.cs.

```
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage =new NavigationPage( new tabbedpage.TabbedPage1());
        
    }
```

then Tabbedpage.xaml:

```
<TabbedPage
x:Class="FormsSample.tabbedpage.TabbedPage1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsSample.simplecontrol">
<!--  Pages can be added as references or inline  -->
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <local:Page1 />
    <local:Page3 />
    <local:Page4 />
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Wanting to navigate Page1 from Tabbedpage to other page.

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="FormsSample.simplecontrol.Page1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
Title="page 1">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout x:Name="Contenttest">
            <Button
                x:Name="btn1"
                Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
                Text="navigate to another page" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new simplecontrol.Page5());
    }
```

About Navigation detailed info, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical

Comment: i did this                                                                                                                                                  public TabbedPageMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new listofinterest());

            Children.Add(new Map());
            Children.Add(navigationPage);
            Children.Add(new SettingsTab());
        }

Comment: @MiledBilel please provide one simple sample at github to test.